# Pulling GeoJSON data into Leaflet with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, leaflet

I am new to Leaflet and I was wondering how to load markers from a MySQL database onto a leaflet map. How to load markers from MySQL using PHP and ajax?

```
.....{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.340141,47.60894]},"properties":{"name":"Pan
Africa Market","address":"1521 1st Ave, Seattle,WA","type":"restaurant"}},.......
```

Leaflet code:

```
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([47.6145, -122.3418], 13);

            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            }).addTo(map);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "./geojson.php",
            dataType: "geojson", 
            success: function(response) {
                    L.geoJson(response, {
                        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                    }).addTo(map);
            }
         }).error(function() {});


            function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
            }</script>
```

The markers dont show on the map. I tried `type: "POST"` too, I checked chrome console for errors and I got none.

**UPDATED** geojson.php output:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.340141,47.60894]},"properties":{"name":"Pan Africa Market","address":"1521 1st Ave, Seattle, WA","type":"restaurant"}},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.344391,47.61359]},"properties":{"name":"Buddha Thai & Bar","address":"2222 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA","type":"bar"}},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.356445,47.624561]},"properties":{"name":"The Melting Pot","address":"14 Mercer St, Seattle, WA","type":"restaurant"}},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.337654,47.606365]},"properties":{"name":"Ipanema Grill","address":"1225 1st Ave, Seattle, WA","type":"restaurant"}},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.345673,47.612823]},"properties":{"name":"Sake House","address":"2230 1st Ave, Seattle, WA","type":"bar"}},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.340363,47.605961]},"properties":{"name":"Crab Pot","address":"1301 Alaskan Way, Seattle, WA","type":"restaurant"}},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.345467,47.613976]},"properties":{"name":"Mama's Mexican Kitchen","address":"2234 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA","type":"bar"}},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.326584,47.617214]},"properties":{"name":"Wingdome","address":"1416 E Olive Way, Seattle, WA","type":"bar"}},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.342834,47.610126]},"properties":{"name":"Piroshky Piroshky","address":"1908 Pike pl, Seattle, WA","type":"restaurant"}}]}
```

Finally I figured out: there was a missing line in the:

```
$feature = array(
'type' => 'Feature',)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the error is here: `dataType: "geojson"`

jQuery's AJAX supports these values for `dataType`: `xml`, `json`, `script`, and `html` (from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)). It will try to parse the response based on that, and "geojson" is not a value it knows or recognizes. `dataType` is also not to be confused with `contentType` and `mimeType`, these are different things.

What you simply need to do is change that to `dataType: "json"` since GeoJSON files are just JSON.

You received no feedback on errors because there was nothing happening in the `.error` function.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./geojson.php",
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function(response) {
                L.geoJson(response, {
                    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                }).addTo(map);
        },
        error: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
        }
     }).error(function(response) { console.log(response) });
```

Comment: I get this error: `leaflet.js:8 Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.`

Comment: Check your PHP file, it must output just the GeoJSON and nothing else, and it must be valid JSON. Can you add a complete output example to your question?

Comment: Finally I figured it out, it was invalid GeoJSON format, markings are on, but popup function still not working.

Comment: @Balazs Glad you figured it out :) You need to add popups to each feature manually via `onEachFeature`, see here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36161890/1781026 If you need help with that you should open another question